# Call right template specialization for each type of a variadic template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a function `foo()` that takes a list of types `T...` and inside calls another (templated) function called `do_stuff()` for every element of a vector that is passed in. More specifically, we loop over the vector (of length `sizeof...(T)`), and would like to call `do_stuff<Ti>()` for `vector[i]`, where `Ti` is the `i`'th type in `T...`

The information is available at compile time so I guess this is possible, but how we do it nicely?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
T do_stuff(int param);

template <>
int do_stuff(int param)
{
    return int(100);
}

template <>
std::string do_stuff(int param)
{
    return std::string("foo");
}

template <typename... T>
void foo(const std::vector<int>& p)
{
    assert(p.size() == sizeof...(T));
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Won't compile as T is not specified:
        //do_stuff(p[i]);
        // How do we choose the right T, in this case Ti from T...?
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> params = { 0,1,0,5 };
    foo<int, std::string, std::string, int>(params);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a C++17 fold expression:

```
template <typename... T>
void foo(const std::vector<int>& p)
{
    assert(p.size() == sizeof...(T));

    std::size_t i{};
    (do_stuff<T>(p[i++]), ...);
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/krHDZR)

---

Alternatively, you can avoid the mutable `i` variable with `std::index_sequence`:

```
template <typename... T>
void foo(const std::vector<int>& p)
{
    assert(p.size() == sizeof...(T));

    [&p]<auto... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        (do_stuff<T>(p[Is]), ...);
    }(std::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EDmqCT)

Comment: I like the fold solution, but what is happening in the second? Is that... a templated lambda function?

Comment: @DanTony: yes, this is a C++20 feature. In C++17 you would need to create a separate template function that takes the `index_sequence`, resulting in more boilerplate.

Answer (score 4):

What about as follows ?

```
template <typename ... T>
void foo (std::vector<int> const & p)
{
    assert(p.size() == sizeof...(T));

    using unused = int[];

    std::size_t  i{ 0u };

    (void)unused { 0, ((void)do_stuff<T>(p[i++]), 0)... };
}
```

If you can use C++17, see the Vittorio Romeo's answer for a more elegant and concise solution.

Comment: That's UB with multiple `i++` in the one expression, right?

Comment: @Quimby Not when using an initializer list

Comment: This looks very interesting! Where can I read more as to how this actually works? Or is there a simple explanation?

Comment: @Quimby No problem.  Initializer lists and comma operator list provide strong sequencing guarantees that make each element a full expression and each subsequent element sequenced after the preceding elements.

Comment: @DanTony - take also in count that the comma operator (inside the round parentheses) execute the element on the left (so call the `do_stuff()` function) but discard it's result and "return" the value on the right; this way you can execute functions that doesn't return a value (or return not `int` values) inside the initialization of an array of `int`'s. The `(void)` before the `do_stuff()` call is in case the function return a `T` type that redefine the comma operator. The first zero is in case the `T...` list is empty (you can't initialize an `int[]` with an empty initialization list).